# Auto-adjustment of column width for 2 rows of data

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. I have 2 rows and 3 columns of data. In bootstrap, I have to adjust the column width manually using `col-md-(number)`. Is it possible to get bootstrap to adjust the column width automatically?

Below is my html code. The column width was manually set at `col-md-2`

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2"><h4> <b>Col 1</b> </h4> </div>
       <div class="col-md-2"><h4> <b>Col 2</b> </h4> </div>
       <div class="col-md-2"><h4> <b>Col 3</b> </h4> </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2"> {{Col1}} </div>
       <div class="col-md-2"> {{Col2}} </div>
       <div class="col-md-2"> {{Col3}} </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you expect ? I don't really understand...

Comment: Maybe I can have something like `col-md-auto` to make the column width adjustment automatic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in Bootstrap, but you can code it yourself.

> Here is a way with css (just coded with max 5 items : To complete,
>   just need to manage to media queries and complete until 12 items.

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/sGqPKy3rpH

**CSS**:

```
.col-md-auto{
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  float:left;
}

/* 1 item */
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* 2 items */
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div {
    width: 50%;
}

/* 3 items */
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .col-md-auto {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* 4 items */
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ .col-md-auto {
    width: 25%;
}

/* 5 items */
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(5),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(5) ~ .col-md-auto {
    width: 20%;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-auto">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer which will be useful to many StackOverflow members.